# Foundation Dropdown Closing

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm using the jQuery Foundation Top Bar 2.0.1

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Mouse over menu item
2. Drop down opens, move mouse to drop down
3. Mouse mouse off drop down

Behavior in IE: Drop down closes

Behavior in Chrome/Firefox: Drop down stays open

Here's what the menu HTML looks like:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
                        <section class="top-bar-section">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="headerItem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                                <li class="has-dropdown headerItem">
                                    <a href="#">Engine Product</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li><a href="#">Perkins Engines</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Isuzu Engines</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">FPT PowerTrain</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">ISS Engines</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Mitsubishi Engines</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                             </ul>
                       </section>
                </nav>
```

Looking in foundation.topbar.js it looks like this is the function controlling when the hover css class is added/removed from the menu items

```
.on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.top-bar li', function (e) {
          if (!self.settings.is_hover) return;

          if (/enter|over/i.test(e.type)) {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
          } else {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
          }
        })
```

I added a quick logging statement to see what's going on

```
console.log('target: ' + e.target.innerHTML + ' event: ' + e.type);
```

In IE:

```
 target: Engine Product event: mouseenter 
 target: Perkins Engines event: mouseenter 
 target: Perkins Engines event: mouseleave 
 target: Perkins Engines event: mouseleave
```

In Chrome/Firefox

```
 target: Engine Product event: mouseenter 
 target: Perkins Engines event: mouseenter 
 target: Perkins Engines event: mouseleave
```

I'm not really sure what to do about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the zepto mouseleave event is buggy.

My workaround solution: Just use Jquery